# How would you vectorize nested for loop? - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How would you change this nested for-loop into vectorized form in Matlab?

```
for i = 1 : Ix - (Iy-1) 
for j = 1 : Jx - (Jy-1)
diff = x_im(i:i+(Iy-1), j:j+(Jy-1), : ) - y_im; 
if ( sum ( abs ( diff(:)) ) == 0 )
return;
end
end
end
```

Comment: you will need to show what x and y are; is y a scalar, or the same shape as `x(i:i+(Iy-1), j:j+(Jy-1),:)`?

Comment: x & y were just variables (could have any name). x represents rows while y represents columns.  I have changed them to make less confusing.

Comment: Note: Using `diff` as a variable name is not a good idea, because `diff` is a Matlab function name.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't all that pretty, but here's one solution (I just stuck with x and y here):

```
f = @(i,j) nnz(x(i:i+Iy-1, j:j+Jy-1, :) - y)
[idx, jdx] = ind2sub( [(Ix - (Iy-1)), ( Jx - (Jy-1))], 1:(Ix - (Iy-1))*( Jx - (Jy-1)))
result = any(any(~arrayfun(f,idx,jdx)));
```

So you're looking for instances of the matrix y, embedded in the matrix x, right?  The first line defines an anonymous function that does the atomic operation of subtracting y from a particular subarray of x.  The second line builds a set of indices corresponding to all the subtractions that you want to do.  The final line applies the anonymous function (for subtraction) to the virtual indices from line two.  If result == 1, then there is at least one occurrence of y inside x.  If result == 0, then there is not.  If you would like to know where y occurs within x ( which your original code does not do), change the last line to

```
result = ~arrayfun(f,idx,jdx);
```

and look for any `1`s in the array.  The (i,j) index of the `1` gives you the upper left corner of the corresponding subarray in x.